# CHR in SWI Prolog: Rule guard containing "just removed" constraint does not return, blows stack

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, constraint-handling-rules

A little test code with no particular meaning:

```
:- use_module(library(chr)).
:- chr_constraint foo/1, bar/1, anyone/2.

foo(X) \ bar(Y) <=> anyone(X,Y).

anyone(_,Y) <=> bar(Y) | writef("bar(%w) exists\n",[Y]).
anyone(_,Y) <=> writef("bar(%w) does not exist\n",[Y]).
```

If the above is consulted from the SWI Prolog command line and then run with:

```
?- foo(8),bar(10).
```

there is overflow after some time:

```
Could not reenable global-stack
Could not reenable global-stack
ERROR: Out of global-stack.
ERROR: No room for exception term.  Aborting.
Could not reenable global-stack
ERROR: Out of global-stack.
ERROR: No room for exception term.  Aborting.
ERROR: Execution Aborted
% Execution Aborted
```

However, if the code for the second rule is changed by moving the test for `bar` from the guard ot the head:

```
:- use_module(library(chr)).
:- chr_constraint foo/1, bar/1, anyone/2.

foo(X) \ bar(Y) <=> anyone(X,Y).

anyone(_,Y),bar(Y) <=> writef("bar(%w) exists\n",[Y]).  % changed!
anyone(_,Y) <=> writef("bar(%w) does not exist\n",[Y]).
```

then execution terminates:

```
?- foo(8),bar(10).
bar(10) does not exist
foo(8).
```

Is this an accident of the implementation? It does seem a bit dicey.

Furthermore, the above code was written because I wanted to test whether the constraint to be removed from the store (here, `bar(Y)`) would be available in the body of the rule. Apparently not, it is already gone when the rule body executes; but is this implementation dependent or a necessary or specified behaviour of CHR?

Comment: The introduction says "Only built-in constraints are allowed in a guard. These built-ins should be simple tests, i.e. the same constructs that occur in conditions of the host language." I suspect that because `bar/1` is a CHR rule and not a built-in, you're running into an oddity, but I think the semantics of what you're trying to do are the same with the constraint in the head rather than the guard, right?

Comment: @DanielLyons Yes, they are. This is probably something the compiler should catch.